# Is there a way to make the output image of ckeditor responsive?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I have ckeditor wherein images are responsive on the editor itself but the output which in blade.php (html) are not responsive..

I expect that after editing in the ckeditor image would resize according to the container usually bootstrap..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.on()` method of CKEDITOR.

Ex.

```
CKEDITOR
.on: {
    instanceReady: function() {
        this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
            elements: {
                img: function( el ) {
                    // Add an attribute.
                    if ( !el.attributes.alt )
                        el.attributes.alt = 'An image';

                    // Add some class.
                    el.addClass( 'newsleft' );
                }
            }
        } );            
    }
}
```

Edit: Using bootstrap you need to use `el.addClass('img-fluid');` for responsive images.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have these on **config.js**

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
        elements : {
            img: function( el ) {
                // Add bootstrap "img-responsive" class to each inserted image
                el.addClass('img-fluid');

                // Remove inline "height" and "width" styles and
                // replace them with their attribute counterparts.
                // This ensures that the 'img-responsive' class works
                var style = el.attributes.style;

                if (style) {
                    // Get the width from the style.
                    var match = /(?:^|\s)width\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec(style),
                        width = match && match[1];

                    // Get the height from the style.
                    match = /(?:^|\s)height\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec(style);
                    var height = match && match[1];

                    // Replace the width
                    if (width) {
                        el.attributes.style = el.attributes.style.replace(/(?:^|\s)width\s*:\s*(\d+)px;?/i, '');
                        el.attributes.width = width;
                    }

                    // Replace the height
                    if (height) {
                        el.attributes.style = el.attributes.style.replace(/(?:^|\s)height\s*:\s*(\d+)px;?/i, '');
                        el.attributes.height = height;
                    }
                }

                // Remove the style tag if it is empty
                if (!el.attributes.style)
                    delete el.attributes.style;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What is the problem with the above code? Is it for ckeditor itself or the output also in the html. Is it the same with what you want me to do? The {{$lesson->body_content}} displays the edit file from ckeditor as shown below. I want all image to automatically resize into smaller one because their too big overlapping the container..

```
<div class="card-body" >
              <br>
              <p class="text text-justify">
                Back to: 
              <a href="{{url('users/course/'.$lesson->course->id)}}"><b>{{$lesson->course->title}}</b></a></h3>
              </p>
              <p class="text text-justify">

                {!! $lesson->body_content !!}
              </p>
```